# How to print value from one table to another in between the given time?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two tables. I want to copy data from one table to another table (Result) between the given time. So if I change the input time, only the values between these times should be copied for all columns. Can anyone help?

screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

[workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArYn8TW3_a3d4UHVl5k4SrTwQIAl)

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? There is a plenty of solutions, how would you like to solve it? Would Filtering the data work? A pivot table would do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

In R11, put `=IF(AND($Q11>=$F$3,$Q11<=$F$4),C11,"")` and drag till the end.

Also note that for this formula to work.. your start time MUST be less then your end time. Eg .. 5:00 AM @ F3 and 11:00 PM @ F4 . ( :

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. it works for the same day but i also want it to work when the time crosses midnight. any solution for that ?

Comment: would index and match work for this case?

Comment: index and match need a list of values to compare n load.. IMHO, can.. but not with your sample table.. you'll need to make a new table that auto-generate a list of time/hrs (based on the input) on column 1, then load the output on column 2-11.

Comment: "when the time crosses midnight." <-- need to add additional if condition.. || if (startTime>endTime, if( or( and(currentTime>=0015hrs , currentTime<=endTime) , and(currentTime>=startTime , currentTime<=2400)  ) , c11 , "" ), <originalFormula> ) || just buzz me which part of the formula you didn't get.. ( :